# Nullpointerexception when trying to open SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, null

I am getting the following line in LogCat that seems to point to a null `dbHelper` when opening my `SQLite` DB.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
    at com.---.---.GasDataSource.open(GasDataSource.java:29)
    at com.---.---.Vehicle.<init>(Vehicle.java:33)
    at com.---.---.GasFragment$1$3.onClick(GasFragment.java:212)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Here is the chain of code listed in the Stacktrace (it references three lines):

1. *Instantiate a new Object:*

   ```
   Vehicle v = new Vehicle(getActivity(), vId); // GasFragment.java:212
   ```
2. *Open the Datasource inside the Object to load existing properties*

   ```
   public Vehicle(Context mContext, int vehicleId) {

   GasDataSource datasource = new GasDataSource(mContext);
   datasource.open(); // Vehicle.java:33
   ```
3. *Do the actual Open method*

   ```
   database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // GasDataSource.java:29
   ```
4. *Supplemental code: GasDataSource constructor:*

   ```
   public GasDataSource(Context context) {
       dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
   }
   ```

I don't understand how `dbHelper` can be null.  The only thing I can think of was the context was null OR thedatabase was closed already because this happened as the app was in the background for a long time and when I opened it up and hit the 'save' button in the Activity (which triggers this code in part).

Can someone possibly identify the cause, if not, what the best way to at least do a null check here?   it seems weird to do it on this line (I have never seen it done before in examples): `dbHelper.getWritableDatabase()`;

Comment: it looks like dbHelper is null, but seems well initialized in the constructor...

Comment: It's be clearer if you'd post the stack trace and the source code that it refers to.  Your attempt to parse it into a chain of code took away valuable information.

Comment: post full code instead

Comment: it's not dbHelper, it's its context that is null. getActivity() must return null, probably because you're calling it too early in the life cycle.

Comment: @duffymo I have added the full `LogCat` with references to the lines below in the code snippets

Comment: Believe the JVM - if it says you have a NPE, then you do.  Is it repeatable?  If yes, then you need to check your assumptions, stop saying that your code is correct, and take a turn through a debugger to see what's null and why.  That will answer your question faster than anyone here will.  It's already been over an hour.  You'd have the answer if you fired up your IDE.

Comment: @duffymo  I am not saying my code is correct; obviously I am not doubting that there is something that is null.  It IS null.  I am having a hard time finding the cause.  It is not really possible to replicate this so turning on the debugger won't help.